# UPS: Getting warehouse's negotiated rates

Tags: ups, shipping-methods

This is the first time a client of us starts selling in the US, so we get to deal with US warehouses and US shipping carriers. My client has decided he wants to ship his packages using UPS.

All products are shipped from a US warehouse (Webgistix), we communicate to their systems via their API, that all goes well.

As you can imagine, Webgistix offers discounted shipping rates over the default UPS rates.

Since UPS offers a lot of methods with a lot of tiers we thought it would be a good idea to use the build-in UPS shipping method and configure it in such a way we can use the Webgistix shipping rates.

In the UPS module we have the ability to 'Enable Negotiated Rates', but we need to connect it with the rates of Webgistix.

The reason I though this might be possible is because I can enter a 'Shipper Number (Required for negotiated rates; 6-character UPS.)' in Magento. I though I'd enter my own API credentials and enter Webgistix Shipper Number to get their rates.

Of course we have already contacted webgistix about this, but they aren't too technical and they don't know how to set this up, they just provided a PDF with thousands of prices and expect us to manage that manually or something...

Is this even possible to use the UPS module? If not, is there another solution or should I enter everything manually.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPS negotiated rates is pretty simple - see here for full setup - http://www.webshopapps.com/blog/2012/01/ups-negotiated-rates-in-magento/

But it sounds like you want to get Webgistics negotiated rates on top of that. IMO that would imply they either need to give you a UPS account (which I would very much doubt UPS would allow) or they need to provide an API to connect into rather than UPS (effectively another carrier which is Webgistics).

Comment: I indeed want the rates that Webgistix offers, so it seems that I can't use the UPS module and I'll have to enter them some other way...